# Strange Error, work in one server but not in the other

Tags: php, undefined-function

The code bellow, while works in one server doesn't work to another

```
abstract class XCTemplate
{
    private static $_instances  =   array();

    public static function Instance($params = array())
    {
        $class = get_called_class();

        if(!isset(self::$_instances[$class]))
        {
            self::$_instances[$class]   =   new $class($params);
        }

        return self::$_instances[$class];
    }
}
```

The error I am getting from the above code is the following:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_called_class() in /home/mysite/public_html/wp-content/themes/mysite/Libray/class_template.php on line 36
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php: `(PHP 5 >= 5.3.0)` - so most likely you have a lower version on the machine where you get the error. (Btw., would it have been so hard to look that up in the manual yourself?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the server where it doesn't work is not running PHP 5.3 or later. You can easily verify your PHP version by calling [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php).

The error you're getting is expected if it's running < PHP 5.3.

[Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php)

> **get_called_class**
>
> (PHP 5 >= 5.3.0)

Answer (score 1):

[get_called_class](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.get-called-class.php) exists since version 5.3. Isn't one of your servers running an older version?